# Publishing a Three.js Web App to an FTP Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, three.js, ftp

I'm working on a Three.js web application, and I'm looking for guidance on how to publish it to my FTP server. I've successfully developed the app and tested it locally, but now I need to make it accessible on the web.

Here's an overview of what I've done so far:

1. Developed a Three.js.
2. Tested the app locally, and it works as expected in my development environment.
3. 1. Have access to an FTP server where I want to host the app.

Now, I'm seeking help with the following:

- What are the necessary steps to prepare my Three.js app for deployment?
- Are there any specific configurations or settings I need to be aware of for hosting Three.js apps on an FTP server?
- Any best practices or tips to ensure a smooth deployment process?

I'd greatly appreciate any insights, guides, or recommendations from the community on how to publish my Three.js web app to my FTP server successfully. Your expertise will be invaluable in helping me take this project to the next level.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's no different than publishing any JavaScript code to the web. It must be mounted, using a `<script>` tag, to the HTML code read from whatever file the browser navigates to on your server. Beyond that your server must be configured to serve files to web using a webserver like Apache2 or Nginx.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.